# actionscript 3 :error. type coercion failed

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

I am getting following error when trying to simulate `CalendarLayoutChangeEvent` on a `DateField` object.

> cannot convert
>   mx.events::CalendarLayoutChangeEvent@feb667 to
>   mx.events.CalendarLayoutChangeEvent

I am dispatching events on swf's which are loaded at runtime.

any help will be appreciated.

```
private function setDateField(child:Object, dateString:String):String
{                   
    child.selectedDate = compileDateValue(dateString,child.formatString);
    var changeEvent:CalendarLayoutChangeEvent = new CalendarLayoutChangeEvent("change", true, false, null, new Event("change"));
    var retval:String;
    try
    {
        retval = String(child.dispatchEvent(changeEvent));
    }
    catch(e:Error)
    {   
        trace(e);
    }
    return retval;
}
```

Comment: Could you show us the code that you did used ?

Comment: this code is from main swf and I am dispatching event on DateField object of loaded application swf.

Comment: I tested your code (with some edits) and I didn't get any error ! It's working fine with a `DateField` inserted in the stage ...

Comment: I think, this issue is related to different application domain. In Main swf file multiple swf files are loaded at runtime. This way I can able to simulate events on loaded application into Main swf.

Comment: And how did you load those SWFs in the main one ? And is the child is a `DateField` object when you call the `setDateField()` function ? ...

Comment: I use LoaderInfo class object to get currently loading swf in browser. As MainSprite = loaderInfo.content.root as Sprite and assign it as child of stage.Hence, I can access multiple swf's at a time in single browser window. Yes I use DateField object to dispatch event.

Comment: Sorry, I was a little bit busy ... So, are you using a `Loader` object or an `SWFLoader` component or what exactly ? I think that the problem is coming from SWF loading, could you add the code that you've used for that (how did you load your SWF an how did you access the `DateField` object/component inside that loaded SWF) because I tried a very simple example using an `SWFLoader` with a `SystemManager` and it's working fine ...